# Container UIView alignment to the bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xcode5

I'm trying to aligning a container UIView to the bottom of the screen in such a way it always is at the bottom of any device whatever the resolution or height is but I can't figure out how to do this via the storyboard.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: YEs using auto layout

Comment: In the storyboard I'm not seeing any way to position my container view relatively to the parent UIView. It's all based on neighbors. And the option to align the edge is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a vertical constraint between your view and its container view with a constant of your desired space between the views.

One way via IB is to CTRL-Drag from your view to the container view and select bottom space to bottom layout guide.

[image]

Make sure to check the constant after creating the layout constraint to have the correct value since ib will use the current distance for the two views.

Comment: Alleluiah!! That does it. Thanks a lot. I now have to deal with 6.1 vs 7 differences since I'm not getting the same behavior in the simulator.

Comment: I'm having one small issue: when I switch to a 3.5 screen, the bottom container is now invisible. I'm assuming it's pushed down. I use autolayout so I thought that wouldn't happen. Thanks!

Comment: have you made constraints for the container too?

Answer (score 0):

Use autolayout ([official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)), or you can do this:

```
// Assuming you want to move a UIView *foo

CGFloat screenHeight = [[[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] size] height];

CGRect newFrame = foo.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = screenHeight - foo.frame.size.height;

foo.frame = newFrame;
```

---

With autolayout:

[image: Adding New Constraints]

In this picture, in the top most part of the pop up dialog, the drop down menus with the numbers will let you choose what to set the constraint relative too.  Try this.

Comment: I tried that earlier but ran into an issue where if I tap the container, with the tap triggering a modal view, the container goes back to its "hardcoded" position on the storyboard. And I have no idea why.

Comment: Probably because of autolayout.  Try putting these lines in this method of your view controller: `-(void)layoutSubviews { [super layoutSubviews]; /*place view*/ }`  But you can also just use autolayout constraints to position the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like the solution on top made it stop jumping from the new position.